# Single Sign-On - How to Force User First be Connected to Corporate Network?

Tags: single-sign-on

In this [Frequently Asked Questions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.sso.meta/sso/sso_faq.htm) article,  there is a question

> Does single sign-on work outside my corporate firewall?"

The answer is :

> Yes, single sign-on can work outside your corporate firewall. When users are outside the corporate firewall, they can use their network passwords to log in to Salesforce. **Alternately, you can require that users must first be connected to your corporate network in order to log in.**

I want to know that how to "require users must first be connected to your corporate network".
It's by IP restrict or other ways? If by IP restrict, is it also work with VPN ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to be configured on the external identity provider (aka your corporate environment) you use for SSO.
IP restrict is another validation, and could be used in addition, or might be even preventing users from be able to enter a domain password from not allowed IP addresses.